# Why is Blazor Server a stateful app framework?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Context: based on the docs of [Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server) it says, *Blazor Server is a stateful app framework.*

It comes to my attention that when I created an application written in Blazor server it seems to have a persistent connection to the server because if I leave it for couple of minutes or so, a prompt shows disconnection. I have been writing server-based app written in PHP and all I know that http is a stateless but not sessionless.

My issue is SignalR sometimes overwhelmed by a series of connections and multiple http requests, thus making signalR disconnected and all the loaded values in a variable is lost.

So my question, is there a way to make it stateless. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Switch to Blazor Webassembly.

Comment: It's not possible as of the moment because it would take so much time and effort.

Comment: No, there is no way to make it stateless.  This is why I've always personally been totally uninterested in the server variant.  Cory is correct that if you want stateless, you want WebAssembly.  Sorry, don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: Okay thank you for those answers of you all. I might move them to WebAssemby variant.